# Jquery mobile 4 framework failed to load SVG%3E image

Tags: jquery-mobile

I upgraded jquery mobile framework 1.1.1 to 4.0 in my project. when i try to run project locally in google chrome, I'm getting error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request). Please guide how to fix this issue

Jquery Version : 1.10.2

**error message**

data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22iso-8859-1%22%3F%3E%3C!DOCTYPE%20svg%20PUBLIC%20%22-//W3C//DTD%20SVG%201.1//EN%22%20%22http%3A//www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd%22%3E%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%20id%3D%22Layer_1%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/1999/xlink%22%20x%3D%220px%22%20y%3D%220px%22%20%20width%3D%2214px%22%20height%3D%2214px%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2014%2014%22%20style%3D%22enable-background%3Anew%200%200%2014%2014%3B%22%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23FFF%22%20d%3D%22M13.621%2C5.904l-1.036-0.259c-0.168-0.042-0.303-0.168-0.355-0.332c-0.092-0.284-0.205-0.559-0.339-0.82%20c-0.079-0.153-0.073-0.337%2C0.017-0.486l0.549-0.915c0.118-0.196%2C0.088-0.448-0.075-0.61l-0.862-0.863%20c-0.162-0.163-0.414-0.193-0.611-0.075l-0.916%2C0.55C9.844%2C2.182%2C9.659%2C2.188%2C9.506%2C2.109C9.244%2C1.975%2C8.97%2C1.861%2C8.686%2C1.77%20c-0.165-0.052-0.29-0.187-0.332-0.354L8.095%2C0.379C8.039%2C0.156%2C7.839%2C0%2C7.609%2C0H6.391c-0.229%2C0-0.43%2C0.156-0.485%2C0.379L5.646%2C1.415%20C5.604%2C1.582%2C5.479%2C1.718%2C5.313%2C1.77c-0.284%2C0.092-0.559%2C0.206-0.82%2C0.34C4.339%2C2.188%2C4.155%2C2.182%2C4.007%2C2.093L3.092%2C1.544%20c-0.196-0.118-0.448-0.087-0.61%2C0.075L1.619%2C2.481C1.457%2C2.644%2C1.426%2C2.896%2C1.544%2C3.093l0.549%2C0.914%20c0.089%2C0.148%2C0.095%2C0.332%2C0.017%2C0.486C1.975%2C4.755%2C1.861%2C5.029%2C1.77%2C5.314c-0.053%2C0.164-0.188%2C0.29-0.354%2C0.332L0.379%2C5.905%20C0.156%2C5.961%2C0%2C6.161%2C0%2C6.391v1.219c0%2C0.229%2C0.156%2C0.43%2C0.379%2C0.485l1.036%2C0.26C1.582%2C8.396%2C1.717%2C8.521%2C1.77%2C8.687%20c0.092%2C0.284%2C0.205%2C0.559%2C0.34%2C0.82C2.188%2C9.66%2C2.182%2C9.844%2C2.093%2C9.993l-0.549%2C0.915c-0.118%2C0.195-0.087%2C0.448%2C0.075%2C0.61%20l0.862%2C0.862c0.162%2C0.163%2C0.414%2C0.193%2C0.61%2C0.075l0.915-0.549c0.148-0.089%2C0.332-0.095%2C0.486-0.017%20c0.262%2C0.135%2C0.536%2C0.248%2C0.82%2C0.34c0.165%2C0.053%2C0.291%2C0.187%2C0.332%2C0.354l0.259%2C1.036C5.96%2C13.844%2C6.16%2C14%2C6.39%2C14h1.22%20c0.229%2C0%2C0.43-0.156%2C0.485-0.379l0.259-1.036c0.042-0.167%2C0.168-0.302%2C0.333-0.354c0.284-0.092%2C0.559-0.205%2C0.82-0.34%20c0.154-0.078%2C0.338-0.072%2C0.486%2C0.017l0.914%2C0.549c0.197%2C0.118%2C0.449%2C0.088%2C0.611-0.074l0.862-0.863%20c0.163-0.162%2C0.193-0.415%2C0.075-0.611l-0.549-0.915c-0.089-0.148-0.096-0.332-0.017-0.485c0.134-0.263%2C0.248-0.536%2C0.339-0.82%20c0.053-0.165%2C0.188-0.291%2C0.355-0.333l1.036-0.259C13.844%2C8.039%2C14%2C7.839%2C14%2C7.609V6.39C14%2C6.16%2C13.844%2C5.96%2C13.621%2C5.904z%20M7%2C10%20c-1.657%2C0-3-1.343-3-3s1.343-3%2C3-3s3%2C1.343%2C3%2C3S8.657%2C10%2C7%2C10z%22/%3E%3Cg%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E

---

[image]

Comment: Who h jquery version are you using along with JQM 1.4? Please post some html markup.

Comment: Jquery Version 1.10.2

Comment: I'm getting this error in Jquery Mobile library 4.0.

Comment: note that many changes are made to jQM 1.4 It's not possible to know the error's source without more details. I just tested it on Chrome, it's working. Are you overriding any classes? are you following the new changes in HTML markup of jQM 1.4?

Comment: Please find error attachment with details. I didn't override any classes, just added jquery mobile js,css and images files to project and tried to run it and encountered above issue.

Comment: this is weird. try a simple page with some buttons. `<a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-edit">Test</a>`